# Generating an awkward JSON data model directly from a Java class and GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, data-modeling

Can I build a class that will model this JSON data?

```
{
    "PROPERTY":[
    {
        "Integer":["String", "String"],
        "Integer":["String", "String"],
        "Integer":["String", "String"],   
    }
    ]   
}
```

I'm stuck using this JSON data.
I can almost get the right model with these two classes.
But I can't get it exact.

```
public class ClassObject {
    public Map<Integer, String[]> PROPERTY;
}   

{
    "PROPERTY":
    {
        "Integer":["String", "String"],
        "Integer":["String", "String"],
        "Integer":["String", "String"]   
    }  
}             

----

public class ClassObject {
    public List<Map<Integer, String[]>> PROPERTY;
}          

{
    "PROPERTY":[
        {"Integer":["String", "String"]},
        {"Integer":["String", "String"]},
        {"Integer":["String", "String"]},    
    ]    
}
```

Comment: try Map<Integer, List<String>>

Comment: How do you plan to deal with duplicate names? It's undefined in the JSON specification.

Answer (score 4):

What about this one :

```
public class ClassObject {
    public Map<Integer, String[]>[] PROPERTY;
}
```

?

Comment: How do you init this :
    Map<Integer, String[]>[] MY_NAME =

Comment: Like any array, do you have a specific issue ?